# Correct index creation to avoid duplicate indexes

Tags: mysql

I have a condition where a different combination is used for the same columns in the where clause of the select query. Can someone please suggest creating a useful index to avoid duplicate indexing?

Below are the where clauses used in the 8 select queries.

```
 WHERE job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1 AND  jobtitle LIKE '%registered nurse%' AND company='Sunrise Hospital' AND location='Las Vegas, NV, US'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25;

WHERE job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1  AND company='Sunrise Hospital' AND location='Las Vegas, NV, US' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25;

WHERE job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1 AND  jobtitle LIKE '%registered nurse%' AND company='Sunrise Hospital'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25;

WHERE job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1 AND  jobtitle LIKE '%registered nurse%' AND location='Las Vegas, NV, US' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25;

WHERE job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1 AND  jobtitle LIKE '%registered nurse%'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25;

WHERE job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1 LIMIT 25;

WHERE job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1  AND location='Las Vegas, NV, US'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25;

WHERE job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1 AND  company='Sunrise Hospital'   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25;
```

Columns Datatypes:

```
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`job_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1'
`is_deleted` tinyint(1)
`jobtitle` varchar(250) NOT NULL
`company` varchar(250) NOT NULL
`location` varchar(250) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Create 2 indices - by `(company, location, job_status, is_deleted)` and by `(location, company, job_status, is_deleted)`. If job_status and is_deleted are used as boolean (contains only 0 or 1) then use not `job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1` but `job_status = 1 AND is_deleted = 0` and put these columns at the beginning of the above indices expressions.

Comment: so if I'm going to use `job_status = 1 AND is_deleted = 0` then I've to create the 2 indexes as below right?
`( job_status, is_deleted,company, location)` and by `( job_status, is_deleted,location, company)`

Comment: If I'm going to use `job_status != 0 AND is_deleted != 1` then do I've to create the 2 indexes as `(company, location, job_status, is_deleted)` and by `(location, company, job_status, is_deleted)`

Comment: sorry `job_status` will not be only 0 or 1, it may contain 2, 3, or 4 as well. And `is_deleted` contains only 0 or 1.

Comment: boolean values in indexes are useless and are ignored because they have a cardinality of just 2. You will get a small speed up due to index covering all predicates and thus avoiding an IO operation to fetch the row when not matching all predicates.

Comment: Equiation can be processed by the index search whereas unquiation by index scan. If so then move these columns first and apply `WHERE job_status IN (1,2,3,4) AND is_deleted = 0`

Comment: @Bohemian This is true for an index by separate column, but not for composite index where the next components can be searched too.